# DID / SHOULD + BUT. Which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

I came across some English exercises for which I don't know the correct answer and I couldn't find any information on this kind of sentence construction.

1. What did/should he do but kiss her.
2. At that moment who …… into the room but his first wife.
    a) was walking     b) did walk     c) should walk     d) walked

English is not my first language, so if you know the answer and could also provide an explanation it would be really helpful. Thank you! :)

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Depending on the context I can see several answers to those cloze sentences.

Comment: I **suspect** that the required answer in both cases uses *should*. But either would work for (1) and three of the four alternatives for (2). Is there any further context, or are these sentences all you have to go on?

Comment: See https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/who-what-should

Comment: There is nothing wrong with *any* of the answers. Barring further criteria and context, no single answer can be given.

Comment: You should ask questions like this on English Language Learners. If you take my advice I will write “and what did she do but go there”.

Answer (score 0):

From the context and possible answers you could infer that the answers they expect to see both involve *should*. This is not the best reason to choose them but this is not the place to get answers to your homework.

*Should* when used normally as in He should turn on a light, or should put out a fire describes what some one might do or possibly could do. But when combined with Who or What then should is setting the stage for, or describing as a if in a story (a meta-description) what is happening. The question is rhetorical (not expecting an answer) in that they are answering it immediately. This is commonly meant as the seemingly inevitable outcome of what is described.

The rain chased us into the shack. Then what should happen but the roof crashed down on us. This can be read as "Then what do you think happened next? The roof came down."

The answers "Did" and d) would also be OK for English but would have missed the lesson being given.